# Rephrasing "get to do" structure

Tags: difference, verbs

If I rephrase the following sentences:

> #1 After a time you **get to** realize that these things don't matter.
>
> #2 You'll like her once you **get to** know her.
>
> #3 His drinking is **getting to** be a problem.
>
> #4 She's **getting to** be an old lady now.

into:

> #1' After a time you will realize that these things don't matter.
>
> #2' You'll like her once you know her.
>
> #3' His drinking is becoming a problem.
>
> #4' She's becoming an old lady now.

Is there subtle difference in meaning?

Answer (score 2):

The main effect of using "get to" in this context is to soften the expression.

For example: in your last example, I would suggest the actual "translation" is not

> She is becoming an old lady now.

but:

> She is an old lady now.

This is a very blunt statement, so it is softened with:

> She is getting to be an old lady now.

to avoid sounding rude. Similarly, talking about someone's drinking problem is a sensitive subject; your "translation" sounds a lot blunter than the "getting to" variant. For example, I would expect to hear:

> Jones is your responsibility. His drinking is becoming a problem. I expect you to handle it.

but

> Mrs. Jones, we need to talk about your husband. His drinking is getting to be a problem.

There is also an element of regional dialect, especially in your first example. As a native speaker of Mid-Atlantic American English, I would be more likely say "start to realize" or "come to realize." "Get to realize" to me suggests regional influence (probably from the American South) and informality. I would not suggest using it in a formal or professional context.

Comment: Thx. If I replace "come to realize/know" with "realize/know" in my first two examples, will they sound awkward? Will they have different meaning from the original ones? @chapka

Answer (score 1):

I'll go through them in order.

**1:** 'Getting to realise' isn't really the right English for this context. What you've said is correct, but there is a subtle difference between the two:

The first phrase speaks generally, in the present tense. You've replaced it with the future tense, which changes the meaning very slightly. To maintain the identical meaning, I would say '*After a time you **come** to realise...*'.

**2:** 'Getting to know someone' is a common phrase in English and I wouldn't bother replacing it given the choice. Your change is almost identical in meaning, but there is an even more subtle difference between the two:

'Getting to know someone' implies you've met them once or twice, but will warm to them once you've seen them **a bit more**. So, add those three words to get an identical meaning: '*You'll like her once you know her **a bit more***.'

**3 & 4:** You're spot on using the verb 'to become' here. The meanings are, as far as I can tell, identical.

Comment: I agree with you about everything, though I do wonder a bit about #4. Is it _becoming an old lady_, or _starting to become an old lady_? I don't quite have a sense for this, but I think might be either of those... What do you think?

Comment: The most common way to say it is simply 'she's getting older', but if you can't use 'get' the best verb to substitute in is 'become'. "Starting to become" is a bit wordy in this context.

Comment: True - but I was getting at the underlying meaning, not the best way to rephrase that meaning.